# get subfolders without For Each Loop?

Tags: vb6

Is there any method in vb6 to get the Subfolder name without using For Each Loop?

Most of thread suggests using For Each with FSO, but what if I want to get the subfolder name of specific Folder? e.g. Folder next to C:\Windows ?

I badly need this method to minimize the process time in my program. Simply escaping the loop isn't enough for me.

Comment: Exactly which folder do you need the name of?

Comment: The system consists of collecting subfolder information and using timer to keep the program active while scanning. Current code requires to get the whole bunch of subfolder using For Each Loop. When system breaks (since its using timer) at C:\Program Files, it scans again the directory C:\ to find if the folder next to C:\Program Files exists, for my computer, it will return C:\Program Data.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish exactly? I don't mean the steps of your algorithm; I mean: what's the goal of the system?

Comment: Personal Anti Virus Software. I already have working one, but need more speed.

Comment: You actually think you are going to outprogram commercial virus scanning software in VB6 when you aren't sure how to get a folder? Good luck with that.

Comment: As I said, I already have one. Just need to boost more speed.

Comment: Unless you have a good reason to, don't use the FSO.  This is far slower than using the Dir$() function or making the API calls yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking what I think you are (how to list the subfolders of `C:\Windows`), the answer is no, not without looping.

The reason is that internally the VB FSO uses [`FindFirstFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), along with the accompanying `FindNextFile` and `FindClose` you'll find linked on that page) to iterate the subfolders of a specified folder. The loop is necessary once `FindFirstFile` has found the first match in order to call `FindNextFile` to continue retrieving the folders, and `FindClose` once the last match has been found and the next iteration fails.

Comment: The FSO is far "fatter" than just calls to those APIs.

Comment: @Bob77: Where did I say that the FSO was merely these API calls? It internally uses many, many API calls. This question asked about a specific part of the FSO's functionality, not the entire FSO in general. If you have a way to list the subfolders without looping, please post it as an answer to demonstrate. Your downvote based on something I didn't say (or even imply) isn't quite fair.